# How do I return the 'top member of each group' in this sorted table/list?

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
  WINS       MEMBER_ID     GROUP_ID
   2            45            1 
   2            65            1
   1            30            1
   1            20            2
   1            50            2 
   1            40            3
```

So What I am trying to do is return the top "Member_ID" in each GROUP (groups are specified by GROUP_ID) determined by the number of wins; with the tie-breaker going to the member with the lower Member_ID #.
(The table is already sorted/listed in the 'correct order').

How Do I grab the winner of each group?

The desired output is below:

```
MEMBER_ID
  45
  20
  40
```

Thanks in advance.

(Edit, this is what I've tried):

```
SELECT max(player_id)
     , max(wins)
     , group_id
  FROM table;
```

(I know this is wrong but I am not sure which analytic function I will have to use)

Comment: SO is not a free coding service website.  Make some attempt to create your own query.  If it doesn't work, we can try to help.

Comment: @Eric sorry, i forgot to mention that I know that some sort of analytic function needs to be used but I just wasn't sure which one. I was completely stumped and knew that my guess was not even close but i put it on there anyways. What would I have to do so that you 'undownvote' my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little help of analytic functions:

```
SQL> with test (wins, member_id, group_id) as
  2    (select 1, 40, 3 from dual union all
  3     select 1, 50, 2 from dual union all
  4     select 1, 20, 2 from dual union all
  5     select 1, 30, 1 from dual union all
  6     select 2, 65, 1 from dual union all
  7     select 2, 45, 1 from dual
  8    )
  9  select member_id
 10  from (select member_id, row_number() over (partition by group_id
 11                                       order by wins desc, member_id asc) rnk
 12        from test
 13       )
 14  where rnk = 1;

 MEMBER_ID
----------
        45
        20
        40

SQL>
```

Comment: I think you want row_number() instead of rank(). Otherwise you can have ties on first place

Comment: Yes, @Juan; but, how to decide which one to pick? I guess both. Or just one? We'll see what the OP thinks. It is easy to fix it, right?

Comment: OP already said `member_id` is the tie breaker and you already include it on the `order by`

Comment: Do you think I may be over abusing the question system? I noticed i got downvoted :( want to make this a learning experience so i don't get booted from the forums. haha.

Comment: I don't know who & why downvoted your question. I don't think you're abusing it. I don't have any problems with your questions so - as far as I'm concerned, you're good.

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot

Comment: No problem at all :)